# Python 3.5.3 KeyError: 0 returned from random.choice()

Tags: python-3.5

here's my code:

```
fList = {7:7, 9:9}

def checkList():
    if not None in fList:
        print(fList)
        fL = random.choice(fList)
        ttt[fL] = computerLetter
        del fList[fL]
        print(fL)
        print(ttt)
        print(fList)
```

Python throws me this error:

```
{9: 9, 7: 7}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jason/Desktop/Programming/Python3_5/TestCode.py", line 35,     in <module>
    checkList()
  File "/home/jason/Desktop/Programming/Python3_5/TestCode.py", line 22, in checkList
    fL = random.choice(fList)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/random.py", line 265, in choice
    return seq[i]
KeyError: 0
```

This was working fine when there were move key:value pairs in the dictionary. I'm having trouble understanding whats wrong. Thank you in advance for your time and attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at your code it seems you expect `random.choice` to choose a key from you dictionary, so what you need to do is:

```
random.choice(list(fList.keys()))
```

BTW, I don't think you are using you conditional (`if`) properly. Currently it means that it will be executed only if fList doesn't have a key `None` (i.e. if your list was `fList = {7:7, 9:9, None:5}` it wouldn't execute). What I think you meant is `if fList is not None`, this means that it will only execute if it is defined

Comment: Thank you. I want to run that if statement as long as the dictionary isn't empty. In your opinion what would be the best way of doing that?

Comment: The Pythonic way is to write `if fList` which evaluates to `True` when there are values inside the dictionary and `False` when it is empty. Since you're using a dictionary, why are you calling it a f*List*?

Comment: No real reason. I just decided on a name.